# how can I show yesterday's page view statistics in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

I want to show yesterday page view statistics statistic in kentico10
I have used page view web part, but it doesn't include yesterday field as shown below.
[image]

But it doesn't include yesterday field!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to clone the biult in webpart (Page Views) which creates a copy of the webpart in the database and copies the code files to the filesystem. Then you would edit the StatisticsType property, add in a new value for yesterday

Yesterday would be added in a value into the datasource:

[image: Kentico 12 Web Part Properties]

Then in the C# code behind of the .cs class you would edit Reload data to handle the yesterday query the way the other queries are handled.

[image: C# code of Kentico Page Views webpart]

You would simply set the correct fromDate, startDate, and Interval type to represent "yesterday".

I don't recommend editing the built in webpart because that is not a 100% upgrade safe change.